# Extract the nth to nth characters of an string object

Tags: powershell, split

I have a filename and I wish to extract two portions of this and add into variables so I can compare if they are the same.

```
$name = FILE_20161012_054146_Import_5785_1234.xml
```

So I want...

```
$a = 5785
$b = 1234

if ($a = $b) {
  # do stuff
}
```

I have tried to extract the 36th up to the 39th character

```
Select-Object {$_.Name[35,36,37,38]}
```

but I get

```
{5, 7, 8, 5}
```

Have considered splitting but looks messy.

Comment: `$_.name.Substring(35,4)`

Comment: Thanks! That was easy - I should have known that and had a mental block!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. One of the most straightforward, as PetSerAl suggested is with `.Substring()`:

```
$_.name.Substring(35,4)
```

Another way is with square braces, as you tried to do, but it gives you an array of `[char]` objects, not a string. You can use `-join` and you can use a range to make that easier:

```
$_.name[35..38] -join ''
```

For what you're doing, matching a pattern, you could also use a regular expression with capturing groups:

```
if ($_.name -match '_(\d{4})_(\d{4})\.xml$') {
    if ($Matches[1] -eq $Matches[2]) {
        # ...
    }
}
```

This way can be very powerful, but you need to learn more about regex if you're not familiar. In this case it's looking for an underscore `_` followed by 4 digits (`0-9`), followed by an underscore, and four more digits, followed by `.xml` at the end of the string. The digits are wrapped in parentheses so they are captured separately to be referenced later (in `$Matches`).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach: returns `1234` substring four times.

```
$FileName = "FILE_20161012_054146_Import_5785_1234.xml"
# $FileName

$FileName.Substring(33,4)         # Substring method (zero-based)

-join $FileName[33..36]           # indexing from beginning (zero-based)

-join $FileName[-8..-5]           # reverse indexing:
                                  # e.g.     $FileName[-1] returns the last character

$FileArr = $FileName.Split("_.")  # Split (depends only on filename "pattern template")
$FileArr[$FileArr.Count -2]       #      does not depend on lengths of tokens
```